# Only one video is visible from a multiple-value field

Tags: entities, files, nodes

I have a field named hudl_videos for embedding videos and I have added multiple values to the field.  I use the Embed and the Video modules where I can embed Youtube and Vimeo videos, but videos from HUDL aren't visible.

Why does this happen?

Comment: **How** did you create this field? And **how** are you displaying it? Voting "too broad" now.

Comment: how are you showing these videos? have you made a views or by node?

Comment: i have a field named hudl_videos and i embed the url into the field. i have the field to allow unlimited but only one is showing up. the videos aren't YouTube or Vimeo they are from a company called hudl.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide all needed details.

Comment: I am trying to embed videos on my site. I have the embed module and the video module where I can embed youtube and vimeo videos.  However, I have a site that called hudl that uses a different platform. When I add the link to the field it doesnt showup.   All other videos (YouTube and Vimeo) are visable on the page. The hudl videos are not.

Comment: The Embed module only has a dev release for Drupal 8 - have you confirmed that module definitely supports Hudl videos? If not, that's likely to be the issue. If that is the case, please open a feature request on the module's issue queue to ask for support for the new provider